# Is it possible to match a string with two equal parts and a separator

Tags: regex, string, go, re2

I'm trying to come up with a regular expression that would allow me to match strings that have equal parts and a separator between them. For example:

```
  foo;foo <- match
  foobar;foobar <- match
  foo;foobar <- no match
  foo;bar <- no match
```

This could be easlily done with PCRE by using positive look-ahead assertion:
`([^;]+);(?=\1$)` The problem is, I need this for a program written in Go, using Re2 library, which doesn't support look-around assertions. I cannot change code, I can only feed it with a regex strings.

Comment: Do you need to match only the first part? Because your regex will still match the full string if you remove the positive lookahead. ```([^;]+);\1$```

Comment: I need to match the whole string. I tried without lookahead, but \1 is also not supported. `\1 backreference (NOT SUPPORTED)`

Comment: To my knowledge you'll have to do it programmatically, i.e. capture the first group, then use it in a subsequent regex checking for «patt»;«patt»

Comment: If the separator is a fixed single character like `';'` and the strings are short, REs are overkill in the first place and a simple find-the-separator check-the-string is the way to go even if you have a fancy RE package. Backreferences in REs tend to be computationally expensive.

Comment: Please use https://github.com/glenn-brown/golang-pkg-pcre package

Comment: As noted in the description, I cannot change the code. The only option is to find a suitable regex.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid the problem cannot be solved only with regex. So I have two solutions for you.

### Solution 1 (using regex)

NOTE: This solution works if the string contains only one separator.

```
package main
import (
  "fmt"
  "regexp"
)

func regexMatch(str string) bool {
  pattern1 := regexp.MustCompile(`^([^;]+);`)
  pattern2 := regexp.MustCompile(`;([^;]+)$`)

  match1 := pattern1.FindString(str)
  match2 := pattern2.FindString(str)

  return match1[:len(match1)-1] == match2[1:]
}

func main() {  
  fmt.Println(regexMatch("foo;foo"))  // true
  fmt.Println(regexMatch("foobar;foobar"))  // true
  fmt.Println(regexMatch("foo;foobar"))  // false
  fmt.Println(regexMatch("foo;bar"))  // false
}
```

### Solution 2 (using split)

This solution is more compact and if the separators can be more than one you can easily change the logic.

```
package main
import (
  "fmt"
  "strings"
)

func splitMatch(str string) bool {
  matches := strings.Split(str, ";")

  if (len(matches) != 2) {
    return false
  }

  return matches[0] == matches[1]
}

func main() {
  fmt.Println(splitMatch("foo;foo"))  // true
  fmt.Println(splitMatch("foobar;foobar"))  // true
  fmt.Println(splitMatch("foo;foobar"))  // false
  fmt.Println(splitMatch("foo;bar"))  // false
}
```